# Create Content item in Orchard CMS programmatically with fields

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content type Event define in back office.
This content type has a location text field and a date field.
I went to create a content item with its two fields.

```
ContentTypeDefinition contentTypeDefinition = _contentDefinitionManager.GetTypeDefinition("Event");
var contentItem = _contentManager.New(contentTypeDefinition.Name);

var titlePart = contentItem.As<TitlePart>() ?? new TitlePart();
contentItem.Weld(titlePart);
titlePart.Title = "Title Content Item";

contentItem.Content["location"] = "acccessmeans";

_contentManager.Create(contentItem, VersionOptions.Published);
```

what can I do?